# Join On sub-query Not working "Alias Issue" -Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery, alias

I have to join two sub queries in **Postgres** and I am writing the following query;

```
(select email, name from testing) AS  x
join 

(select distinct email from testing) AS y 
on x.email=y.email
```

it gives me error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
> LINE 2: (select email, name from testing) AS  x

Comment: First, a SQL query usually starts with `select`.  Second, please explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: share full query not partial

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
select *
from (
  select email, name 
  from testing
) AS  x 
  join (
    select distinct email 
    from testing
  ) AS y on x.email = y.email
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
select x.email, x.name, y.email
from testing as x
  join (
    select distinct email from testing
  ) AS y on x.email = y.email
```